# Class not Found: Laravel Artisan via ssh

Tags: php, ssh, laravel-5.1

for a Laravel 5.1 project I am trying to setup a beta version of this project on a shared hoster. Everything works fine except for `artisan`.

I do login through ssh and move to the Laravel project directory and the not matter what `php artisan` command I use I get following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Queue\ConsoleServiceProvider' not found in /www/htdocs/***/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 543
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'Illuminate\Queue\ConsoleServiceProvider' not found

Any ideas on what could be wrong?
The autoloading should work correctly as the project works fine using the browser.

Comment: Delete the file `bootstrap/cache/services.json`, then run `php artisan optimize`. This last command will generate the services again

Comment: But what to do if even `php artisan optimize` throws the same error?

Comment: Then try `composer update`

Comment: That was the matter o.O Thx @manix

Comment: Nice!  Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

The steps by @manix helped me a lot:

1. Delete file `bootstrap/cache/services.json`
2. call `composer update`
3. run `php artisan optimize`